# Is there a way to start a docker container in bluemix and see the command line output?

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, ibm-cloud

I am having problems to run my docker container on bluemix. The container runs without any problem in my local machine but crashes in bluemix. Is there a way to start a container in bluemix via the "ice" command and see the console output in the same way as I can see it without the "-d" command in my local docker installation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the console output of IBM Containers with the following command line:

```
ice logs <container id>
```

Comment: Great! It works and it helped to solve my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the tool you use:

```
ice logs <container id>

cf ic logs <container id>

docker logs <container id>
```